# Update all rows in a table based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, if-statement, while-loop

I have a table called Training which has rows like Employee ID, Hours, is3ManDay. In this table there may be multiple records corresponding to the same Employee.

I have to calculate Hours related to each Employee ID and I did it like this

```
SELECT EMP_ID, SUM(HRS) AS TOTALHRS, is3ManDay
from Training
GROUP BY EMP_ID, is3ManDay
```

Works perfectly fine but now I want to update is3ManDay to either Yes or No based on the total hours each Employee has

```
@Emp_ID int,
@is3ManDay varchar(10)
IF (SELECT SUM(Hrs) FROM Training WHERE Emp_ID = @Emp_ID) >= 36
BEGIN
   UPDATE Training
   SET is3ManDay = 'Y'
   Where Emp_ID = @Emp_ID
END
ELSE
   UPDATE Training
   SET is3ManDay = 'N'
   Where Emp_ID = @Emp_ID
```

This one also works good BUT with this one I have to manually change @Emp_ID and execute the stored procedure which is not practical. I want to include a loop into this chunk of code but if I remove @Emp_ID it will update all rows with the same value because there is no ID selected.

```
WHILE (SELECT SUM(HRS) FROM Training) >= 36
BEGIN
   UPDATE Training
   SET is3ManDay = 'Y'
END
```

I tried WHILE statement but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to be procedural.  Use SQL:

```
UPDATE Training
SET is3ManDay = 'Y'
Where Emp_ID in 
(SELECT Emp_ID FROM Training HAVING SUM(Hrs) >= 36)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this one.

I never knew SQL was this powerful.

Answer (score 0):

```
merge into Training x
using (
    select emp_id, case when sum_hrs >= 36
                        then 'Y' else 'N' 
                   end as is3ManDay
    from (
        select emp_id, sum(hrs) as sum_hrs
        from training
        group by emp_id
    )
) y
    on x.emp_id = y.emp_id
when matched then
    update set is3ManDay = y.is3ManDay
```